# Effects of using black separation crystal?

Tags: dark-souls-2

What are the actual consequences of using this item?  Item description states 'beware fickle use of this item'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the uses of the stone (Informative to those who doesn't know):

- Sends back phantoms in your world (not invaders) to their world.
- You being the phantom, this stone sends you back to your world (Also works if you're an invader).
- Vanishes NPC phantom allies (beware as their summon sign won't appear again even after resting at the bonfire. A friend of mine mentioned that it shows up again if you reload the game.
- If you're the host and use it, you can see your victories as a phantom.

***Actual Answer***

The reason for the "beware fickle use of this item" warning is because if you use it either as a phantom or as a host to send back people, you are committing a sin. I've only tested it as the host sending someone back and it did add me sin.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, the use of this item does not count toward disconnecting you from cooperative play. This is only caused by "unlawful" disconnecting (resetting your console/pulling the ethernet etc.) and will not cause you to need to use the Bone of Order.

Comment: Does it still reward the one you summoned when you leave?
For example: You are invading as a member of the Bell Covenant, but they decide to gang up and you bail out right away.